# How do I get rid of PNG invisible borders?

Tags: css, html, web

I'm new to web programming, recently I've been asked to make some home pages for someone.
Unfortunately I've run into some problem, the homepage will be on a touch screen for touch input, I've got reports like buttons most of the time doesn't work when clicked on, one of my suspects is invisible borders caused by PNGs.
TL;DR - http://puu.sh/6HQez.jpg The corner of the red button is being blocked by the invisible border of the purple button, are there any ways to fix that?

EDIT: No I'm not asking for how to remove the dotted line, I made them visible to show you.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to capture clicks?

Comment: You could use SVGs instead of PNGs. Or one image and a `<map>`

Comment: I tried z-index before I posted this, forgot to mention that, it wouldn't work out, since it would just turn the situation opposite- making the red button on top.

Comment: @Musa Till now I'm still not sure how does <map> work. EDIT: Actually I know how to use it, but I can never get the coords right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are referring to is not an 'invisible border' but an 'invisible background'.

Your PNG files are rectangular shaped when it comes to event handling, even if some parts are transparent.

If you need to disable some elements from being clicked, you can go about it few ways:

1. Disable `pointer-events` with CSS to make sure that a specific
   element does not caputre clicks.

   `#mypurplediv {pointer-events: none;}`
2. Use Z-index to decide the hierarchy of your elements:

   `#mypurplediv {z-index: 0;}`

   `#myrediv {z-index: 1;}`

**EDIT:**
Per your comments, it seems that you need to retain the abiity to click on ALL elements.
As I mentioned above , your current PNGs are actually rectangles with some parts being transparents.
So you have these options:

1) Use SVG which are vector based shapes (that will by default not have invisible backgrounds). [Good tutorial here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-scalable/).

2) Use image mapping and `area` to create your shapes and give them `href`. [This is a good tutorial about image mapping](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_image_map.htm).

```
example - <area shape="poly" coords="74,0,113,29,98,72,52,72,38,27" href="index.htm">
```

3) Use 3rd party javascript/jQuery libraries such as [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with the first method is it pretty much cancels out the link attribute I had on it, yeah these buttons work by <a>'s.

Comment: And the z-index wouldn't seem to help, forgot to mention that I tried z-index before.

Comment: @341464 I revised my answer to point you to the right direction.

Comment: Fixed using area map! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

That dotted border is called focus outline. You can turn it off by applying CSS to the image.

`img { outline: none; }`

Comment: No actually, I made it visible to show you guys what I meant by that.